# Geocoding/Georeferencing with CARTO BUILDER possible?

Tags: carto, geocoding, georeferencing

Is there any way to do Geocoding with CARTO BUILDER?

1st file: markets.csv with my markets and the coordinates in separate x and y columns; I can upload the .csv but of course I do not have a useful geometry.
2nd file: spreadsheet with addresses (street, city, country, ...)

Both cases were easily to be done with CARTO EDITOR, but I can't find the options in CARTO BUILDER anymore. Is is just a paid service or have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, now geocoding is an analysis that can be added to a layer. So in order to get your data geocoded please follow these steps:

1. Click "ADD ANALYSIS" just below your layer name.
2. Select "Georeference" and click on "ADD ANALYSIS".

[image]

3. Then, select the type of geocoding analysis you want to apply (depending on your data): Lon/Lat, Street Address and so on.

[image]

4. Set the parameters and click on "APPLY".

Comment: OMG, it seems, that I was completely blind! Found and in use, thank you so much.

Comment: Well, this new version is a little weird! Now I can see my points at the positions where I want them, but there is no geometry in the Dataset, is this how it is supposed to be? In the Map I can export the dataset as a Shapefile, GeoJson, ... In the Dataset-Overview it is only possible as a CSV (as there is no Geometry)

Comment: This approach makes sense for the following reason. Imagine that you have a sync table or you want to edit, add or remove some of your data (you can check this). So when opening or refreshing again your map, the geocoding will automatically be updated. You do not need to add the Georeference analysis again and again (as with the Editor).